# Custom font does not work on real android device after build as android

Tags: react-native, expo

I used the custom font on react-native expo project.
It works well on the expo platform with an android emulator.
But After I built my project as APK file, it does not show all the text as my custom font.
I followed the tutorial like this (`https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-custom-fonts/`) but it doesn't work.
Is there any solution to work on android?

I tried to use the custom font like this.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    fontLoaded: false
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      "Antonio": require("./assets/fonts/Antonio-Light.ttf"),
      "Antonio-Bold": require("./assets/fonts/Antonio-Bold.ttf")
    });
    this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { fontLoaded } = this.state;
    if (!fontLoaded)
      return (
        <Text>Loading.....</Text>
      );
...........
```

This is my package.json file.

```
...


  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "angle-normals": "^1.0.0",
    "art": "^0.10.1",
    "bunny": "^1.0.1",
    "expo": "^34.0.3",
    "expo-asset": "latest",
    "expo-asset-utils": "^1.1.1",
    "expo-font": "^6.0.1",
    "expo-gl": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-pixi": "^1.2.0",
    "expokit": "^32.0.3",
    "gl-mat4": "^1.1.4",
    "gl-react": "^3.13.0",
    "gl-react-expo": "^3.16.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "matter-js": "^0.13.0",
    "native-base": "^2.10.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-motion": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-33.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-donkey-kong": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-extended-stylesheet": "git+https://github.com/bberak/react-native-extended-stylesheet.git",
    "react-native-game-engine": "^0.10.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.2.1",
    "react-native-paper": "2.1.3",
    "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.11.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.2",
    "react-navigation": "^3.2.1",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^2.0.9",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-style-proptype": "^3.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "regl": "^1.3.0"
  },

...
```

This is my app.json file.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Zenduja",
    "slug": "Zenduja-Pro",
    "privacy": "unlisted",
    "sdkVersion": "33.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover",
      "backgroundColor": "#222222"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/fonts/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.aaa.aaa"
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "assetExts": [
        "ttf",
        "mp4",
        "otf",
        "xml"
      ]
    },
  }
}
```

Please help me.
Thanks.

Updated question.

This is my expo snack loading font project.

https://snack.expo.io/@angelsinej/font-loading

Comment: Can you reproduce in expo snack?

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I mentioned it does not work after built as an APK file.
I will reproduce in expo snack right now and let you know after done.

Comment: but it;s work in snack?

Comment: check in you app.json:  assetBundlePatterns":

Comment: like: "assetBundlePatterns": ["assets/fonts/*.*"]

Comment: Of course, It works on mobile, but not working in the released APK version.

Comment: My app.json missed this section. I will add it and try to build as apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to app.json like:

```
"assetBundlePatterns":["assets/fonts/*"]
```

Update to sdk 34 and related react-native package.

and recompile apk

Comment: I updated the my question with app.json. I added the this above section but I could not see the changed custom font on android device after build apk.
Would you please check my app.json?

Comment: I updated the answer with * syntax, please rebuild apk. If will not work: rename apk to zip and look at assets if files will exist.

Comment: I rebuilt apk, but not work. And I checked my apk as a zip file, there are two TTF font files named `asset_2a8a6af373531a3500e240604935b8dc.ttf` and `asset_975aacd71c6910b732c678b04b39ed86.ttf`.
Is that right?

Comment: Repost your app.json

Comment: Can you try with  expo-fonts 7.0.0 package  version?

Comment: React-native package to https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz

Comment: If you are working with expo 34 please also update In app.json sdkVersion": "33.0.0", to 34.0.0,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200605/discussion-between-oleg-and-nikolai-serg).

Comment: Thanks, It works well now. I updated the package and rebuilt apk.
Then another problem occurred by updating the package.
It doesn't load the custom font when I run on the expo platform.
I tried to do like this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52917558/cant-seem-to-load-custom-fonts-with-expos-font-loadasync?rq=1` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I still have this issue on android. I'm using expo sdk 35. I've tried all the different solutions listed here including "assetBundlePatterns":["assets/fonts/*"] any thoughts?